# Powershell: Where-Object wildcard

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to search all the properties of an Active Directory user for a particular phone number/extension.

I can get all the properties like so:

```
get-aduser joesmith -Properties *
```

but I want to filter the results for, say extension 1234 (which may be in many places, like extensionAttribute1, OfficePhone, HomePhone, Mobile, etc).

I tried:

```
get-aduser joesmith -Properties * | where-object {$_ -like "*1234*" }
```

but where-object wants $_.value, and I don't know the precise value.

How should I search the values for multiple properties?  I'd like to see results like:

```
mobile        1234
officephone   12345
othermobile   61234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate through the values for properties you don't know the names of (i.e OfficePhone, CustomAttribute2, mobile), you can use the following:

```
get-aduser joesmith -Properties * | foreach-object { 
  foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($property.value -like "*1234*") {
      "$($property.name) $($property.value)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use Get-Member such as: `get-aduser joesmith -prop *|gm -MemberType Property|select -ExpandProperty name|%{if($test.$_ -match "@philips"){[pscustomobject]@{Name=$_;Value=$test.$_}}}` ...that might give you something easier to work with too.